# Can I view system stats in the Terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal

The widget [iStat Pro](https://www.apple.com/downloads/dashboard/status/istatpro.html) allows to monitor different system stats like

- CPU usage
- network bandwidth in/out
- memory usage
- ...

How can I view such system stats in the Terminal?

[image]

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Depending on what you want displayed there are several options available using Terminal:

- `top`: real-time sorted display of running processes such as memory and CPU usage
- `iostat`: I/O summary statistics for terminal, device and CPU operations
- `vm_stat`: Mach virtual memory statistics
- `diskutil list`: disk/volume capacity
- `df`: used/free space on mounted partitions
- `fs_usage`: real-time file activity for both disk and network
- `nettop`: updated information about the network (a bit like `top` for net I/O)
- `w`: who is logged in and what they are doing; plus a brief system load summary
- `ifconfig` and `ipconfig`: network interface and IP protocol details

Most of these commands have a huge list of options.  It's probably best to consult the `man` pages for details.

I usually rely on:

- `top -u -s 10` to identify CPU-hogging processes;
- `fs_usage -f filesys` or `fs_usage -f network` to identify processes generating a lot of disk/network load.

Answer (score 9):

The [iStats ruby gem](https://github.com/Chris911/iStats) lets you see the CPU temperature via the command-line.

#### Installation

`$ gem install iStats`

#### Usage

`$ istats`

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 6):

You can use `top`. It'll show CPU & RAM usage together with all the processes. It'll also show you network packets in/out, and discs data read/written.

Comment: And with `man top` you can see how to customize the output.

Answer (score 4):

The above are great commands.  Also, I like to use

```
$ du -ks *
```

To show how much disk space all the folders below my current directory are using.

This command lists the top 10 directories in order of size:

```
$ du -sh * | sort -nr | head -10
```

For an overall system stats tool, I like the python glances better than top:

https://nicolargo.github.io/glances/

This is how you can install it on MacOS using the [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) package manager:

```
$ brew install glances
```

This is how you can install it on Debian/Ubuntu:

```
$ sudo apt-get install glances
```

This is how you can install it on CentOS/Red Hat:

```
# yum  install glances
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are having network problems, especially with a server exposed to the Internet, lsof(1) can be extremely useful. It lists all open files.

For example, `lsof | fgrep '/Library/WebServer/` will show you all the files that are open on your web server. I've been using this a lot to find and ban "leeches" and "bots" who are reducing my bandwidth by automatically sucking down file after file.

Answer (score 2):

My preferred way to see CPU usage with a single command that returns instantly is

```
ps -axro pcpu | awk '{sum+=$1} END {print sum}'
```

`-ax`: all processes, including non-terminal processes and ones you don't own.

`-r`: sort by cpu usage

`-o pcpu`: only output the %cpu field. %cpu is a 1-minute average of the process, but will only average over the lifetime of the process if its lifetime is <1min.

`awk`: sum the first column in each line and print the sum at the end.

This is a per-core CPU metric, so on a 12 core CPU you can get up to 1200; you're not capped at 100.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two commands for determining your local and public IP:

#### Local IP

```
ipconfig getifaddr en1
```

This is when using Wi-Fi. For ethernet use `en0`.

#### Public IP

```
curl whatismyip.org
```

Comment: On current MacBook Airs (which don't have an ethernet port) the Wi-Fi device code is `en0`. You can find out what it is with `networksetup -listallhardwareports | grep -E '(Wi-Fi|AirPort)' -A 1 | grep -o "en."`.